# How to change solr.jetty.request.header.size in docker

Tags: solr, docker

I have created a Solr version 8.1.1 in Azure using a Docker for Sitecore. I get the following error for a large query:

```
ERROR Error during executing a query.

Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException

Message: <h1>Bad Message 431</h1><pre>reason: Request Header Fields Too Large</pre>

Source: SolrNet

   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options)

   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1.ExecuteQuery(SolrCompositeQuery compositeQuery, QueryOptions options)

 

Nested Exception

 

Exception: System.Net.WebException

Message: The remote server returned an error: (431) Request Header Fields Too Large.

Source: System

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()

   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)

   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by redeploy the Docker instance by updating the YML file with the following setting under environment section.

```
- SOLR_OPTS=-Dsolr.jetty.request.header.size=65535
```